# Get PHP array from XML responce with namespaces

Tags: php, arrays, xml, decode, geo

I receive an XML repsonce from a GEO service (PDOK). The $responce->raw_body contains this XML structure:

```html
<xls:GeocodeResponse xmlns:xls="http://www.opengis.net/xls" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
   <xls:GeocodeResponseList numberOfGeocodedAddresses="1">
      <xls:GeocodedAddress>
         <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:28992">
            <gml:pos dimension="2">121299.73296672151 487003.8972524117</gml:pos>
         </gml:Point>
         <xls:Address countryCode="NL">
            <xls:StreetAddress>
               <xls:Street>Rokin</xls:Street>
            </xls:StreetAddress>
            <xls:Place type="MunicipalitySubdivision">Amsterdam</xls:Place>
            <xls:Place type="Municipality">Amsterdam</xls:Place>
            <xls:Place type="CountrySubdivision">Noord-Holland</xls:Place>
         </xls:Address>
      </xls:GeocodedAddress>
   </xls:GeocodeResponseList>
</xls:GeocodeResponse>
```

How can I access the elements in here. For example I want an PHP array to access the element 121299.73296672151 487003.8972524117
to grap the coordinates.

And also the other elements. I used SimpleXML parser but I recieve always null.
I think it has someting to do with the namespaces. But I have no clue how to solve this.

The responce is coming from:

```
        $url = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/geocoder/Geocoder?zoekterm=xxxxx%20xx";
        $response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
        ->expectsXml()
            ->send();
```

```
        $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response->raw_body);

        print_r( $xml);
```

output:

SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: So show us how you used SimpleXML

Comment: $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response->raw_body);
 
  print_r( $xml);

Comment: And how do you get `$response->raw_body`

Comment: I am not a dentist, please dont make me pull teeth here

Comment: Turn on your PHP error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found a solution for my problem. Its indeed by the namespaces and when using xpath after the namespace registration you can find the elements you need.

```
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xls', 'http://www.opengis.net/xls');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gml', 'http://www.opengis.net/gml');

    foreach($xml->xpath('//xls:GeocodeResponseList') as $header)
    {
        $geocoordinates =  $header->xpath('//gml:pos');
        $street =  (string) ($header->xpath('//xls:Street')[0]);
        $place =  (string) ($header->xpath('//xls:Place')[2]);

    }

    echo $geocoordinates[0];              // get the coordinates needs to split on space
    echo "<br />";
    echo $geocoordinates[0]['dimension']; // get the dimension attribute
    echo "<br />";
    echo $street;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $place;
```

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file); 
    foreach($xml->xpath('//xls:GeocodeResponseList') as $header)` also works, no need to register namespaces...

Answer (score -1):

Use "->expectsJson()" instead of "->expectsXml()". Then do this:

`$array = json_decode($response->raw_body);`

or if you use PHP 7.x: https://github.com/eddypouw/geodata-postal-api

Comment: It is not possible to force the output to Json 
Message: 'Unable to parse response as JSON'